# Video loaded using NetStream hangs in 10.0.2.54, but plays in 10.1.x.x Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, video

Good day!

I'm loading flv file using Video and Netstream (trivial example from docs). On Flash player 10.1 everything works fine. On 10.0.2.54 everything stops on NetStream.Play.Start. May be this is some well known bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here what I found here: http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/10/Flash_Player_10_Release_Notes.pdf

Flash Player 10.0.2.54 is included with initial release of Flash CS4 Professional. This build was not deployed publicly to the Web. Users should update to the newest version of Flash Player 10 for content development and testing. Updated versions of the content debugger and other players are posted on the Flash Player Support Center Downloads page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real cause was (I suppose) garbage collection. My NetStream instance was declared as local variable inside custom class' method. I've moved it to be class variable and it works.

Here what I found here: http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/10/Flash_Player_10_Release_Notes.pdf Flash Player 10.0.2.54 is included with initial release of Flash CS4 Professional. This build was not deployed publicly to the Web. Users should update to the newest version of Flash Player 10 for content development and testing. Updated versions of the content debugger and other players are posted on the Flash Player Support Center Downloads page.